# Framework7 <a href=""> not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-framework-7

I have a simple `<a>` in a page which is using `FrameWork7` as follows:

```
<li><a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="images/icons/black/users.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Go Google/span></a></li>
```

But when I click on that it is not redirecting to google page. I have checked console and it shows as follows:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
framework7.js:12307 XHR failed loading: GET "https://www.google.com/".$.ajax @ framework7.js:12307app.get @ framework7.js:1652app.router.load @ framework7.js:2648load @ framework7.js:636handleClicks @ framework7.js:7573handleLiveEvent @ framework7.js:11488
```

I am new to `Framework7`. I have purchased a template for development.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the [docs](https://framework7.io/docs/link.html#bypass-links-handler) says :

> It is possible to bypass F7 link handler (if you want to add custom
>   logic to link, or want it to direct to external website). In this case
>   we need additional `external` class

```
<a class="link external" href="http://google.com">Open Google</a>
```

You want link to outside of your Framework7 application, so just add `external` class to your `a href` and its working properly

```
<li><a href="https://www.google.com/" class="external"><img src="images/icons/black/users.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Go Google</span></a></li>
```

and see you have typo on write down the closing span tag

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clossed the span, also add a target:

```
<li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/black/users.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Go Google</span></a></li>
```

Comment: not working. It is not the span issue, it is related with Framework7

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error message OP provided

Comment: Yep srry, it's about same origin policy. Javascript is limited by the "same origin policy" for security reasons so that a malicious script cannot contact a remote server and send sensitive data.

Comment: @ A. Wolf how should i fix it?